# preloader animation don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to add a preloading animation to my web page.

I found this code that I tried to apply,

However while the CSS works fine, the JS don't the annimation is permanently displayed.

my html :

```
<head>
    <script>
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
              overlay.style.display = 'none';
            })
    </script>
    <title>Verify Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay">
    <div class="spinner"></div> 
    </div>
```

my CSS :

```
    .spinner{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;

    border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top:3px solid #f25a41;
    border-radius: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;

    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#overlay{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 }
```

I am a complete noob in JS I might have simply applied it the wrongg way .. or called it the wrong way... don't know... where is my mistake?

Will this also work when my page will process a form or should I modify something to make this preload also appear when form is getting processed?

Comment: your code is working look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the visibility to hidden of overlay element.

```js
overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    overlay.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://httpbin.org/get", true);
xhttp.send();
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 3px solid #f25a41;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have it working for loading the page, however it doesn't when I submit my form during the form being processed
what should I change?

Comment: @agone07 are you submitting form via ajax ?

Comment: @agone07 after processing the form via ajax you will hide the spinner in response. i have edited the answer. check it

Comment: @agone07 its not possible to show or hide the spinner using PHP. if you are submitting the form to the current page via PHP then you will place this overlay.style.visibility = "hidden"; code in body onload function to prevent it from keep spinning.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

May I recommend jQuery as an option? If so this is very simple to do, here is a working example with your code.  I included a 3 second timer so you can see it action - or else the page loads so quick you never see it.

https://jsfiddle.net/3f4c32qh/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //fires when page is done loading

  setTimeout(
    function() 
    {
      //only need this part..however page loads fast
      //so this makes a 3 second pause
      $("#overlay").hide()
    }, 3000);

});
```

Actually this is such a common practice there is a shorthand for it:

```
$(function(){

 //stuff to do once page has loaded

});
```

However, if you want to do a pure JS approach - you're example works just fine!  Just make sure you're putting the JS in the end of the body, right before the closing body tag, not in the head section.  Here is a JSFiddle with your original code:

https://jsfiddle.net/be9g1a0b/2/

[image: See my Javascript settings]

Comment: I replaced my code by yours... however I think with jQuerry I have something to request first in my head ...

What should I add? (I am a complete 100% beginner)

Comment: Ok it works ... thanks; however it doesn't appear when y form is being processed ... do I have to change something?

Comment: @agone07 you mentioned just preloading animation prior - are you wanting to trigger this animation when a user submits a form on the page?